# Looking for JMonkeyEngine tutorials and documentation

Tags: java, jmonkeyengine

I'm looking for tutorials and documentation for JMonkeyEngine, beside the material on the official website. Any clue?

Comment: any specific areas/topics you are looking for? The website seemed to have pretty decent documentation/tutorials so am wondering what direction you are wanting with this.

Comment: Also in most cases I've seen, the official website has more up-to-date documentation than the random old blog posts you might find around the internet, and usually more complete too.

Comment: By my experience, the more source of information you have, the more you get a chance to find one easy to understand for you...

Answer (score 8):

Although mostly from the official site, I thought it was important to mention them as they have a lot of good tutorials.

- [jMonkeyEngine wiki](http://jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/jME%20Wiki) (Important)
- [jMonkeyEngine Forum](http://jmonkeyengine.org/forums-index/)
- [Tutorials](http://jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/jme3#tutorials_for_beginners)
- [Misc tips](http://jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php?id=miscellaneous_tips_collected_by_mindgamer)
- [jMonkeyEngine applet](http://www.streamhead.com/tutorial-jmonkeyengine-applet-hardware-3d-in-the-browser/)
- [jMonkeyEngine2 Tutorials](http://jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php?id=jme2_-_flag_rush_tutorial_series)
- [User Guide](http://jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php?id=user_s_guide)

Comment: Most of the links are invalid now. Returns page not found. Please update links can be really helpful

Comment: @Crawler its been 5 years since the answer has been posted :). Check out github for their source: https://github.com/jMonkeyEngine/jmonkeyengine, their Q&A page (StackOverflow-like): https://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/ for support, and https://wiki.jmonkeyengine.org/ for wiki

Answer (score 1):

I found this:

http://www.theprogrammersweblog.com/2008/12/3d-game-programming-in-java-using.html

Pretty interesting, even if incomplete for the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Try the wiki:

http://jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php

Answer (score 0):

Although not exactly the same technology you might want to check out the lightweight java game library at http://lwjgl.org/ as there seems to be a fair amount of tutorials on it.

Comment: Downvote? JMonkeyEngine isn't as widely used as lwjgl.

Comment: I think it's because it's off-topic...

Comment: Not exactly, I found very little resources for JME but much more on lwjgl.

Comment: Yes, but the poster was looking for information regarding JME.